# Why is Criteria API .not() not functioning?

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, criteria-api

If i leave out the .not() it gives me back the Projects having Events like it should. Now i would expect it to return the Projects without Events if i add the .not() but it just returns nothing.

Function:

```
public List<Project> findAllWithoutEvents(ProjectFilter filter) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Project> cr = cb.createQuery(Project.class);
    Root<Project> fromProject = cr.from(Project.class);


    cr.select(fromProject).where(fromProject.get("id").in(fromProject.joinList("events").join("project").get("id")).not());
    Query<Project> query = session.createQuery(cr);

    return query.getResultList().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Project Class has a OneToMany <-> ManyToOne Relation with Event Class

Comment: I would guess it is because you do a couple of joins from your root `fromProject.joinList("events")` where you do not specify a `JoinType`. As far as I know without a specified `JoinType` the default is `JoinType.INNER`. Meaning your query creates an inner join from your Projects to events, which will already filter out any project that does not have events. You could try specifying `JoinType.LEFT` or use a subquery.

Comment: However, if I were to write a query that was supposed to give all Projects without events, I would probably just try `cb.isEmpty(fromProject.get("events"))` or something like that.

Comment: Your second comment fixed it for me, thanks mate! Thought i already tried it with isEmpty() but i might have used it the wrong way. Still wondering why not() wasn't working.

Comment: Like I said i think it's because your query does create an inner join between your project and event tables. An inner join would already filter out any row in project that cannot be linked to an event even without any where clause.

Comment: If you want add the content of your 1st and 2nd comment as a solution and i will mark it as the accepted solution.